# CSS: Border-top won't work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm trying to fix the border. It will only appear above the text because of the pull right and left. What should I do to make it appear over the whole line?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-left">
          <footer class="footer"><p>text1</p></footer>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-right">
         <footer class="footer"><p>text2</p></footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    padding-top: 19px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #777;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: What if you put the footer class on your *row* div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* without changing your markup.

It makes more sense to give your footer row another fitting class: `footer-row` and apply styles to that instead:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row footer-row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-left">
          <footer class="footer"><p>text1</p></footer>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-right">
         <footer class="footer"><p>text2</p></footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer-row {
    padding-top: 19px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #777;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/0PfVSeqyfj)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
<footer class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-left">
          <p>text1</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <p>text2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Basically, you get rid of your double `footer` element and apply the `container` class to the `footer` element so it expands the whole width and remains as a single `footer` when resized

This solves your issue AND is semantically correct since you won't have 2 `footer` elements

I have added a [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/svo7TignA8) so you can see how it works

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you want text 1 and text two to take up half of the div each, try putting the footer tag as a whole across all columns as one element, then text one and text 2 nested in two divs with columns of 6.

Comment: Kind of worked, the text is now cramped


     <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="pull-left"><div class="col-md-6"><p>text text text</p></div></div>
      <div class="pull-right"><div class="col-md-6"><p>text text tex</p></div></div>
    </footer>    
  </div>
    </div>

http://puu.sh/eKlY7/3d8ae3dd0c.png

Comment: I dont think you need the pull lefts and right any more try taking them out?

Comment: you should then be able to text align center on their parent div if you want to center align the text.

Comment: @Devin is also right to say you could just put the footer with the class of container...